# Merge Accounts and Ban

Tags: support, status-completed, sock-puppets

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1130919/chris-p) and [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726730/user726730) are one and the same.

See chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2288401#2288401

Basically this user created a new account because with their original account they could not post questions anymore

Comment: I have recently seen an asker, who admitted in a comment that he's posting on another account, because the main account ran out of questions. Should I report this account?

Comment: @RobW report away. I have already flagged one of the questions.

Comment: I've had success just flagging one of an offender's posts, with basically the custom flag content you've posted above.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta this is the flag message I used: "``This user is the same as: stackoverflow.com/users/726730/user726730 See here: chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2288401#2288401 claims it is a `friend account` (whatever that means). Can they be merged?``"

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Indeed.  amanaPlanaCanalPanama just [likes to post on meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=793234#793234) =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 :-P ur just jealous

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I have answered many questions of this asker, and I don't think that he's deliberately trying to game the system. Sometimes, his research efforts are bad, but his questions are often honest. For this reason, I don't feel like flagging him. Unless a mod overrules my decision by offering strong arguments *why* I should report him.

Comment: @RobW see the chat transcript. He is a duplicate user.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Sorry if I was unclear, but I am talking about another user. Your topic reminded me of this event, and I was looking for the "official" policy.

Comment: Hmmm this seems to have been rectified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Completed; the new user was merged with the original.

Comment: @Robert When an account is merged, does the owner get any punishments?

Comment: @RobW: Sometimes.  It depends on the severity.  The merge by itself does not exact a penalty.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but the user does get a merging of both accounts' rep. doesnt that sort of game the system because the user should not have gotten the extra rep.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Reputation earned by good posts is legitimate, regardless of the account used; these votes are merged into the original account, along with the posts. Cross-votes made by the sock (or the original account to the sock) are invalidated; that rep is lost.